# Encode utf-8 from redis store

Tags: ruby-on-rails, encoding, redis

I use Redis for storing and managing my locale translations. But I have some trouble with russian words. The fact that the russian words are stored in the format like that:
`"\"\\u0441\\u043a\\u0430\\u043b\\u043e\\u043b\\u0430\\u0437\\u0430\\u043d\\u0438\\u0435\""`
And I dont know how encode this string.
Can someone help me?

Comment: what exactly is your problem here? the sequences are normal unicode characters and redis should not care about that.

Comment: The problem is that I cant render this string in normal format, as russian word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

unless I misunderstand the question, there is no problem:

```
irb(main):001:0> require 'redis'
=> true
irb(main):002:0> redis = Redis.new
=> #<Redis client v3.0.4 for redis://127.0.0.1:6379/0>
irb(main):003:0> redis.set 'test', 'Женя'
=> "OK"
irb(main):004:0> redis.get 'test'
=> "Женя"
irb(main):005:0>
```

Comment: Yes, I try this and everithing looks fine. But I dont understand why I have this trouble

Comment: in another comment you say that you cannot render this word in normal format. and yet here you say that everything looks fine. what does this mean? do you have a code sample?

Comment: If I try your example in rails console everything looks fine. But if I try save new key from my rails app I have this trouble. If you have some spare time check railscasts #256.

Comment: the string is probably escaped somewhere and all these characters like quotes, and backslashes get escaped before being sent to redis.